# Why could GNU sort be hanging for 10 hours+ on this specific file

Tags: linux, gnu, gnu-coreutils, gnu-sort

I'm attempting to merge & dedupe several different versions of the same kind of plain txt file using gnu sort that comes with Ubuntu 18 lts. I have used sort a lot almost daily with no issues sorting files of 1gb+ in size.

However, i have the following command that still couldn't complete when i left it going for 10 hours in the background (around 600mb total of data):

```
find backups -type f -iname 'file0.txt' -o -iname 'file1.txt' -o -iname 'file2.txt' -o -iname 'file3.txt' -exec sort -u {} + > "combined.txt"
```

The sort part is what is causing issues, the rest of the command is irrelevant from my testing. I have cat all the files into a single file of ~600 mb and when i try to sort -u this file, it still hangs for ever even when setting memory buffer to 80% with around 6gb free ram. I also have no issues with disk space.

While it is still running, i have dragged in an unsorted 3gb text file and successfully sorted -u it. I'm doing this in a virtual machine if that could matter.

what could cause this behavior?

Comment: Check with `top` if it is CPU issue or if it's waiting for I/O (in which case this may be a broken/slow disk issue). Try running your `sort` with `strace` to see what's going on. Also there is a `+` sign in your command which looks weird?

Comment: @MartinWickman The + is part of the `-exec` action.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you doing this as a root?

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica i double checked it and my original command is correctly sorting all files with the specified names, not just the first file found.

Comment: @j58765436 I apologize for the confusion, your or'ed conditions relate to filename selection not sort results. (coffee must have run out...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting LC_ALL=C before issuing the sort command or export LC_ALL=C below the shebang at the begging of a script file solved it. Not sure why the particular text added to the text files last update caused the command to get stuck forever without LC_ALL=C though.